# Отобразить двумерную матрицу с выбором размерности через ComboBox C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется ComboBox, в нем размеры матрицы от 2 до 10. Как реализовать, чтоб при выборе размера (из СomboBox) формировалась матрица размерностью равной выбранному значению из ComboBox, и выводились автоматически столбцы и строки матрицы нужного размера, которые можно было бы заполнить.
WPF изучаю пару дней и смог сделать только выпадающий список.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Canvas>
    <ComboBox Margin="10 10 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Count}" 
              SelectedIndex="0"
              MinWidth="40"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    </ComboBox>
</Canvas>
</Window>



public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public int[] Count { get; private set; }
    private const int Min = 2;
    private const int Max = 10;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Count = Enumerable.Range(Min, Max - Min + 1).ToArray();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Разбейте задачу на простые подзадачи. 1) Как узнать, что в комбобоксе поменялось значение? 2) По данному значению, как построить матрицу с таким размером? 3) По данной матрице, как вывести её.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно вычислять матрицу на изменении выбранного элемента из ComboBox'а.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    <ContentControl x:Name="Matrix" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

CODE

```
public class Content {
    const int Min = 2;
    const int Max = 10;

    public Content(ContentControl contentControl) {
        this.contentControl = contentControl;
        items = Enumerable.Range(Min, Max - Min + 1).ToArray();
    }

    readonly ContentControl contentControl;
    readonly int[] items;
    public int[] Items { get { return items; } }

    int selectedItem;
    public int SelectedItem {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set {
            selectedItem = value;
            OnSelectedItemChanged();
        }
    }

    void OnSelectedItemChanged() {
        PrintMatrix();
    }

    void PrintMatrix() {
        var grid = new Grid();
        for(int i = 0; i < selectedItem; i++) {
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < selectedItem; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < selectedItem; j++) {
                var textBox = new TextBox();
                textBox.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray;
                textBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
                Grid.SetRow(textBox, i);
                Grid.SetColumn(textBox, j);
                textBox.Text = i + "," + j;
                grid.Children.Add(textBox);
            }
        }
        contentControl.Content = grid;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Matrix - контрол для вывода матрицы
        DataContext = new Content(Matrix);
    }
}
```